# Footnote in \setarrayelement with memoir class

Tags: footnotes, memoir, expansion

I'm using the `memoir` document class.

I have problems storing a `\footnote` command using `\setarrayelement`.

Here's a simple document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newarray{aaa}{1}{1}
\setarrayelement{aaa}{1}{name\footnote{fn}}

\begin{document}

\getarrayelement{aaa}{1}{\x}

\x

\end{document}
```

I want the `\x` to expand to `name\footnote{fn}`, but I never get that far. I get this error message in `\setarrayelement`:

```
! Use of \@pr@videpackage doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.4 \setarrayelement{aaa}{1}{name\footnote{fn}}
```

Curiously, if I add `\usepackage{forloop}`, which I'm also going to use in my document, after `\documentclass{memoir}`, the error message changes to

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \setarrayelement{aaa}{1}{name\footnote{fn}}
```

How can I store a footnote in `\setarrayelement`? I presume that I need to somehow postpone the expansion of `\footnote` until `\x` is used, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\setarrayelement{aaa}{1}{name\protect\footnote{fn}}
```